# Android Panel Style (Card UI) in Jelly Bean are they usable?

Tags: android, user-interface, panel

aI have been looking at the stock apps on my Google nexus running Jelly Bean, and there are some nice panel styles I would like to use in my own App I was wondering if they are part of the stock UI elements that are available to use?

Here's a screenshot of the panel I'd like to use:

[image]

This screenshot is taken from the Google Maps apps but can be seen in other applications, it has a thin grey border and the bottom border is slightly thicker. Some panels have rounded corners, some I've seen have square corners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not a standard widget.

You can however choose a library which provides these (or equivalent) widgets:

- [Cardslib](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib)
- [Cards-UI](https://github.com/afollestad/Cards-UI)

Answer (score 1):

Also, you could try to see if some of the 9 patches (*.9.png) which are in the folder (on Windows):
**C:\Program Files\Eclipse\adt-bundle-windows-x64**\sdk\platforms\android-16\data\res\drawable-mdpi

May help you in your design.
The part in **bold** is to be replaced by your installation path.

I indicated API level 16, but you can choose among all the ones you have installed
And, of course, you're not limited to look into the mdpi folder. That's just the DEFAULTone.

Comment: Thanks for this, do you know if these Resources are OK to use in my own App, I don't want my app getting pulled from the Play store from using someone elses assets?

Comment: I think they are **open source**, since they are Google's own ones... ;)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone finds this question, right now you can use `CardView` to make cards like the ones shown in the picture.